# d3 zoom event not firing for choropleth chart SVG created in storybook using nivo charts

Tags: svg, d3.js, charts, zooming, choropleth

I created a nivo choropleth chart in storybook and I need to add zoom functionality. I have a d3 zoom function which is supposed to listen for the zoom event on my svg. The zoom event doesn't seem to be firing.

The `StyledResponsiveChoropleth` renders as an SVG in the browser so I am using `d3.select("svg")` to access the chart.

When I zoom the component in the browser, nothing is happening, looks to me like the zoom event is not registering.

When I listen to mouse wheel events, they do show up.

This is my code below:

```
export const ChloropethChart: FC<IChoroplethChartProps> = ({
  props
}) => {
  // ***WHAT HAPPENS WHEN HANDLEZOOM IS CALLED????????????

  const selectSVG = select<SVGSVGElement, unknown>('svg')
  const rect = selectSVG
    .append('rect')
    .attr('width', '600px')
    .attr('height', '600px')
    .style('fill', 'none')
    .style('pointer-events', 'all')

  const handleZoom = (e: any) => {
    selectSVG.append('g').attr('transform', e.transform)
  }
  const zoomBehaviour = zoom<SVGSVGElement, unknown>().on('zoom', handleZoom)

  const initZoom = () => {
    selectSVG.call(zoomBehaviour)
  }
  initZoom()

  return (
    <StyledChoroplethChart height={height}>
      <StyledResponsiveChoropleth
        data={data}
        features={featureData}
        margin={{ top: 0, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0 }}
        colors={colors ? colors : PURPLE_RANGE}
        domain={domain}
      />
    </StyledChoroplethChart>
  )
}

export default ChloropethChart
```

Comment: Everytime you zoom you append a new `g` (containing nothing) and apply the zoom transform on that new `g`: selectSVG.append('g').attr('transform', e.transform)`, this of course does not result in any visible change to the visualization. You want to apply the transform to the svg itself, try removing the append.